# Failed to load response due tookhttp3.internal.http RealResponseBody@d7a7722

Tags: okhttp, openai-api

Failed to load response due tookhttp3.internal.http RealResponseBody@d7a7722 how to solve it I'm not able to get output[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dY5z7.png)

My code is
@Override
public void onResponse(@NonNull Call call, @NonNull Response response) throws IOException {
if (response.isSuccessful()){
JSONObject jsonObject= null;
try {
jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.body().string());
JSONArray jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("choices");
String result=jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).getString("text");
addResponse(result.trim());
} catch (JSONException e) {
throw new RuntimeException(e);
}

```
            }else{
                addResponse("Failed to load response due to"+response.body().toString());
            }
        }
    });
```

I tried to change Different API Key but it shows same error